# Expression must have constant value Eigen matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have been trying to give the matrix size while runtime via a function, for example

```
Eigen::MatrixXd FileReader::load_csv(const std::string & path, const int rows_csv, const int columns_csv) {
    std::ifstream indata;
    indata.open(path);
    std::string line;
    std::vector<double> values;
    int rows = 0;
    while (getline(indata, line)) {
        std::stringstream lineStream(line);
        std::string cell;
        while (std::getline(lineStream, cell, ',')) {
            values.push_back(std::stod(cell));
        }
        ++rows;
    }
    std::cout << "loading";
    return Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<double, columns_csv, rows_csv, Eigen::RowMajor>>(values.data(), rows, values.size() / rows);
}
```

(Above code is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146048/3782963), I am not able to send a constant value of the matrix size to the function, I get `Expression must have constant value` error. Is there any way I could do something like this:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd mat = load_csv("some_path", 20, 30);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<double, columns_csv, rows_csv, Eigen::RowMajor>>
                                          (values.data(), rows, values.size() / rows);
```

The

```
Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<double, columns_csv, rows_csv, Eigen::RowMajor>>
                                           ^^^         ^^^
```

tells the `Map` that the that it should expect a constant sized matrix, and the

```
(values.data(), rows, values.size() / rows);
                ^^^              ^^^
```

is a dynamic sized matrix. If, for some reason, you want to  ignore the shape of the matrix in the file and define it in your program, try:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>>
                                                 (values.data(), rows_csv, columns_csv);
```

Comment: You should use `Eigen::Dynamic` instead of `-1`, however (although the value is unlike to ever change again). And for defensive programming it may make sense to check if every row actually has the same number of entries.

Comment: @chtz Changed to `Eigen::Dynamic`. As for programming defensively, in the question OP linked to, that would be relevant (How do I read a csv file into an Eigen matrix?). In this case (as I understand OP), s/he wants to override the shape of the matrix in the file, whether or not it actually is rectangular.

Comment: But isn't that slower? If I use `Eigen::Dynamic` it seems to be taking quite a lot of memory.

Comment: Slower isn't yet relevant. You can't use a variable as a template parameter, which needs to be resolved at compile time. Also, dynamic or static doesn't change the amount if memory needed, just where it's allocated (heap vs stack).

Answer (score 0):

It is also helpful to read the documentation on [Matrix size allocation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html) which states:

> Fixed-size versus dynamic-size:
>
> Fixed-size means that the numbers of rows and columns are known are
>   compile-time. In this case, Eigen allocates the array of coefficients
>   as a fixed-size array, as a class member. This makes sense for very
>   small matrices, typically up to 4x4, sometimes up to 16x16. Larger
>   matrices should be declared as dynamic-size even if one happens to
>   know their size at compile-time. Dynamic-size means that the numbers
>   of rows or columns are not necessarily known at compile-time. In this
>   case they are runtime variables, and the array of coefficients is
>   allocated dynamically on the heap. Note that dense matrices, be they
>   Fixed-size or Dynamic-size, do not expand dynamically in the sense of
>   a std::map. If you want this behavior, see the Sparse module.