# FFTW returns different results in some loops

Tags: c++, fft, eigen, fftw

I'm new to use C++.
I have tried to implement FFT using Eigen and fftw3 (version 3.3.10).
The purpose is to read measurement data from CSV file and analyze FFT.

However, I realized that fftw returns different results some time (sometimes return results correctly, sometimes wrong results...) in some loops if do some analysis again and again.

The problem might be just a memory leaking or casting variable problem as I'm new to use C++.

I'm very appreciated if you give me any advice or tips.
Thanks in advance!

```
#define EIGEN_FFTW_DEFAULT
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include <fftw3.h>
using namespace Eigen;

// define functions
template <typename T>
T readCSV(const std::string &path);
int nextpow2(int n);
VectorXd offsetData(VectorXd v);
void fftw_test(VectorXd x);

// calculate exponent of next higher power of 2
int nextpow2(int n)
{
    if (n < 0) // n must be int
        return 0;
    if (n == 1) // n
        return 1;

    return (int)floor(log2(n - 1)) + 1.0;
};

// Read Measurement Data
template <typename T>
T readCSV(const std::string &path)
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247057/how-to-read-csv-file-and-assign-to-eigen-matrix
    std::ifstream file;
    std::string line;
    std::string cell;
    std::vector<double> row;
    uint rows = 0;

    file.open(path);
    std::cout << "Opend file: " << path << std::endl;

    std::getline(file, line); // skip the first header line

    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::stringstream lineStream(line);

        while (std::getline(lineStream, cell, ','))
        {
            row.push_back(std::stod(cell)); // insert value as double
        }
        ++rows;
    }
    return Map<const Matrix<typename T::Scalar, T ::RowsAtCompileTime, T::ColsAtCompileTime, RowMajor> >(row.data(), rows, row.size() / rows);
};

void fftw_test(VectorXd x)
{
    // Convert data unit
    x = x * 980.665 * 10;                 // Unit conversion：[G] to [cm/sec^2] to [mm/sec^2]
    int ns = x.size();                    // number of samples
    int nfft = std::pow(2, nextpow2(ns)); // number of fft

    // Zero padding to array
    VectorXd xpad;
    int npad = nfft - ns;

    if (npad > 0)
    {
        xpad = VectorXd(nfft);

        for (int i = 0; i < ns; ++i)
        {
            xpad(i) = x(i);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        xpad = x;
    }

    // /* prepare a cosine wave */
    // for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    // {
    //     in[i][0] = cos(3 * 2 * M_PI * i / N);
    //     in[i][1] = 0;
    // }

    int N = nfft;
    fftw_complex *in, *out, *in2;
    in = (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    out = (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    in2 = (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);

    fftw_plan p, q;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        in[i][0] = (double)xpad(i);
        in[i][1] = 0;
    }

    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE | FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT);
    fftw_execute(p);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("in: %3d %+9.5f %+9.5f I\n", i, in[i][0], in[i][1]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("freq: %3d %+9.5f %+9.5f I\n", i, out[i][0], out[i][1]);
    }

    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_free(in);
    fftw_free(out);
    fftw_free(in2);
    fftw_cleanup();
};

VectorXd offsetData(VectorXd v)
{
    // Offset by mean values
    int ns = v.size(); // number of samples
    VectorXd ones = MatrixXd::Ones(ns, 1);
    v = v - v.mean() * ones;
    return v;
};

int main()
{
    // Read measured data from csv file
    MatrixXd measuredData = readCSV<MatrixXd>("./sampleCsv/20220208-134655_A351AU.csv");

    // Extract a vertical acceleration column
    VectorXd Acc = measuredData.col(4);
    VectorXd Acc_offset = offsetData(Acc / 1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        // fftw bug test
        printf("loop: %ith \n", i);
        fftw_test(Acc_offset);
    };

    return 0;
}
```

The sample CSV file is here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DQO2eeMX7AfxjnuW8DDJMOitxHNuIDHA/view?usp=sharing

The correct results should be below.

```
freq:   0  -0.00000  +0.00000 I
freq:   1 +320.64441 -83.56961 I
freq:   2 -113.66004 -195.80680 I
freq:   3 -28.57778 -13.57046 I
freq:   4 -47.71908 +185.43538 I
freq:   5 +381.01770 +92.18739 I
freq:   6 +430.73267 -348.16464 I
freq:   7 -111.55714 -796.10333 I
freq:   8 -810.79331 -273.42916 I
freq:   9 -624.83461 +607.38775 I
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but for integer operations please don't involve floating-point functions. I'm talking about the `nextpow2` function which should be possible to implement using simple bitwise shifting. And perhaps it should take an `unsigned` argument to avoid the `< 0` case, as well as returning an `unsigned`? You also don't check for the special case of `n == 0`.

Comment: `xpad = VectorXd(nfft);` does not zero-initialize the vector. I'm not sure, why you need that vector if you manually copy that to `in` afterwards.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for your advice! It was not critical but your comment is helpful!

Comment: @chtz Thank you for your advise! It was the critical problem! I deleted ```xpad = VectorXd(nfft);``` and  redefine ```VectorXd xpad = MatrixXd::Zero(nfft, 1);``` That's solved the calculation error!